# I am having trouble understanding what the jal "jump and link" is doing in QtSpim

Tags: mips, qtspim

I need help to understand what the "jal" is doing

Here is the line:

`[00400014] 0c100009  jal 0x00400024 [main]    ; 188: jal main`

Here is the portion of code the line is from:

```
[00400000] 8fa40000  lw $4, 0($29)            ; 183: lw $a0 0($sp) # argc 
[00400004] 27a50004  addiu $5, $29, 4         ; 184: addiu $a1 $sp 4 # argv 
[00400008] 24a60004  addiu $6, $5, 4          ; 185: addiu $a2 $a1 4 # envp 
[0040000c] 00041080  sll $2, $4, 2            ; 186: sll $v0 $a0 2 
[00400010] 00c23021  addu $6, $6, $2          ; 187: addu $a2 $a2 $v0 
[00400014] 0c100009  jal 0x00400024 [main]    ; 188: jal main 
[00400018] 00000000  nop                      ; 189: nop 
[0040001c] 3402000a  ori $2, $0, 10           ; 191: li $v0 10 
[00400020] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 192: syscall # syscall 10 (exit)
```

and how is the number, "0x00400024" significant?

Comment: Download _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_ and read the description of `jal`. As for how 0x00400024 is significant; it says right there in the comment what it corresponds to (the label `main`).

Comment: Its part of the function call sequence.  Here the start code is calling `main` with arguments.